# Error while persisting object into RealmSwift Object type '' not persisted in Realm'

Tags: swift, realm

## **Ok found the problem!**

I was starting a thread to get *members* from web and immediately return the result of query as an observable using RxSwift like this:

```
func getBoardMembersGroupedByType() -> Observable<[MemberType: [Member]]> {

    MeetingRest().getBoardMembers()
        .subscribeOn(OperationQueueScheduler(operationQueue: NSOperationQueue()))
        .subscribeNext { members in DataManager().updateOrInsertObjects(members) }
        .addDisposableTo(bag)

    return DataManager().getObjects(Member)
        .map{ members in members.groupedBy { member in member.memberTypeEnum }
    }

}
```

This line `DataManager().updateOrInsertObjects(members)` was happening before this one `DataManager().getObjects(Member)` and that was the cause.

I think that is a problem on Realm as it should check and create the tables before inserting the same way it does when querying.

## Original Question

I'm trying to persist the following objects into realm but when I run my app I'm getting the error **Object type 'PhoneNumber' not persisted in Realm'**. Whats wrong with it?

- Im using the default Realm configuration.
- XCode 7.3.1
- Swift 2.2
- Realm (0.103.1):

  - Realm/Headers (= 0.103.1)
- Realm/Headers (0.103.1)
- RealmSwift (0.103.1):

  - Realm (= 0.103.1)

The exception is thrown when I try to create the object from a JSON dict.

```
var dict = // Load json object
var member = Member(value: dict)
```

here is the code definition for the Realm objects:

```
class Entity: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int64 = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Member: Entity {
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var email: String!
    dynamic var role: String!
    dynamic var curriculumUrl: String!
    dynamic var curriculumThumbnailUrl: String!
    dynamic var pictureUrl: String!
    private dynamic var memberType: String!

    let phoneNumbers = List<PhoneNumber>()

    var memberTypeEnum: MemberType {
        return MemberType(rawValue: memberType) ?? .Member
    }
}

enum MemberType: String {
    case Member
    case Secretary
}

class PhoneNumber: Object {
    dynamic var number: String!
    dynamic var phoneType: String!
}
```

And here is a sample JSON object that I'm deserializing:

```
{
    "id": 834,
    "name": "Sallie Oneil",
    "email": "sallieoneil@zillan.com",
    "pictureUrl": "http://placehold.it/100x100",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "number": "(998) 477-2928",
        "phoneType": "Work"
      },
      {
        "number": "(898) 467-2201",
        "phoneType": "Mobile"
      },
      {
        "number": "(963) 412-3882",
        "phoneType": "Mobile"
      },
      {
        "number": "(924) 409-2270",
        "phoneType": "Mobile"
      }
    ],
    "role": "eu",
    "curriculumUrl": "http://placehold.it/100x200",
    "curriculumThumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/100x200",
    "memberType": "Member"
  }
```

Comment: Could you share us the code where the error occurs? And best would be the code where you write your objects to Realm as well.

Comment: @Jurik edited the post with more details. Basically its throwing when I try to instantiate the Member type.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing here. Do you have any other classes called `Object` in the scope where you define your class `PhoneNumber`? Then you would need to explicitly inherit from `RealmSwift.Object`.